# How to prove an equivalence?

Tags: functions

How do I prove that $f:\!A\rightarrow\!B$ is injective $\Leftrightarrow$ $\forall C\space$ and$\space \forall g,h:\!C\rightarrow \!A \space , f\circ g=f\circ h \Rightarrow g=h$

I do understand how to prove it left to right, but not vice versa.

edit: I actually didn't prove it correctly for the first time. I wonder if I can prove it this way. If so then I guess I understand how to do it backwards.
$$
f \space inj \space \Leftrightarrow f(x)=f(x')\Rightarrow x=x'\\
\forall x \in \!C, f\circ g(x) = f\circ h(x) \Rightarrow g(x)=h(x)
$$

Comment: What've you tried? As you mentioned, you were able to prove it left to right; why not include this part in your question body with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3584347/edit)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a contrapositive.  Assume $f$  is not injective.

That means there $b,c \in A$ where $b\ne c$ but $f(b)= f(c)$.  So now use that to prove that there must be some $C$ and $h,g: C\to A$ where $h\ne g$ but $f\circ g=f\circ h$.

And make use of the $b,c \in A$ where $f(b)=f(c)$.

Well, $f(b) = f(c)$ so if $h(m) = b$ and $g(m) = c$ we have a point where $h\ne g$ but $f(h(m))=f(h(n))$.  That's a start.

But that's all we need.  Let $C = \{m\}$ and let $h:C\to A$ be $m\mapsto b$ and $g:C\to A$ be $m \mapsto c$ and we have it.  $f\circ g:C \to B$ via $m\mapsto f(b)$ and $f\circ h: C\to B$ via $m\mapsto f(b)$.  So $f\circ g = f\circ h$.

> If $f$ is not injective then there exists a $C$ and an $h,g; C\to A$ where $h\ne g$ but $f\circ g= f\circ h$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f(x) = f(y)$ for some $x,y\in A$.

Consider the map $$g:\{a\}\rightarrow A \qquad g(a)=x$$ and the map $$h:\{a\}\rightarrow A \qquad h(a)=y$$ 
Thanks to $f(x) = f(y)$ we have $f\circ g = f\circ h$. Then, by hypothesis, $g=h$ and then $x=g(a)=h(a)=y$

Answer (score 0):

For the right to left implication, you just need to pick cleverly $C, g, h$ at the right moment.

Assume $\forall C, \ \forall g, h : C \mapsto A,\ f \circ g= 
f \circ h \Longrightarrow g = h$.
We want to show that $f$ is injective, ie $\forall x,y \in A,\ f(x) = f(y) \Longrightarrow x = y$. So consider $x, y \in A$ such that $f(x) = f(y)$. We need to show that $x = y$.

Consider any one-element set, say $C = \{ c \}$. Let $g, h: C \mapsto A$ be defined by $g(c) = x$ and $h(c) = y$.
$f\circ g$ is the function that maps $c$ to $f(x)$, and $f\circ h$ is the function that maps $c$ to $f(y)$. Since $f(x) = f(y)$, we have $f \circ g$ = $f\circ h$. Hence, by the assumption above, we get $g = h$. Hence, $x = g(c) = h(c) = y$, QED.

Comment: What bothers me here is that you are considering a single element set. How do I prove it for any C.

Comment: Like lets say that $x \space and \space x'$ are not in $\space Im(g) \space and \space Im(h)$ then how do we prove f is injective

Comment: @KirillPique You do this action in order:
 (1) Take $x,x'\in A$ such that $f(x)=f(x')$
 (2) Define a set with one element $C=\{c\}$ (you can choose the set what you want because in the hypothesis you have _for all_ $C$
 (3) Define $g,h:C\rightarrow A$ as above (you can do this because in the hypothesis you have _for all_ $g,h$
 (4) End of the proof. 
So there isn't a problem because first you choose $x, x'$ and only after you define $g,h$ (and so $x\in Im(g)$ and $x'\in Im(h)$ by construction$

Comment: @KirillPique Prove *what* for any $C$? Your goal is to prove injectivity, no?

Comment: @OlivierRoche yes it is to prove f injective. But its to prove it $\forall C,\forall g,h:C\rightarrow A$

Comment: @Menezio my problem is that there is a case where both of x values are outside $Im(h)$ and $Im(g)$. In this case shouldn't  there be a case where  the first condition is valid, but there are values where $f$ isn't injective?

Comment: @KirillPique The case where both of $x$ values are outside $Im(h)$ and $Im(g)$ is impossible because first you fix the values of both $x$ and then the functions $f$ and $g$. So by construction you don't have this case